# Tomcat 8 classloading - difference between JAR in [WEB-INF/lib] and [tomcat/lib]

Tags: java, tomcat, jar, classloader, tomcat8

It says [here](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/class-loader-howto.html) that the common classloader is visible to all web application. So what is the difference between having a JAR file within the `WEB-INF/lib` folder of my `war` application and having the same JAR file within Tomcat's `lib` folder?

This JAR is a provider for a Java SPI that I created. When I have it under `WEB-INF/lib`, everything works perfectly. But if I try to put this JAR under Tomcat's `lib` folder (or under `shared/lib` after configuring it in `catalina.properties`) I get errors. The second option is better for me because I need total decoupling of my application and the provider.

The error I get is a `ClassNotFoundException` for the interface that represents my service (which the JAR implements). This interface is in a third project, which is a dependency for my `war` application.

Answer (score 5):

The `tomcat/lib` directory should be used for shared libraries for the whole web server and `WEB-INF/lib` only for one web application.

Answer (score 4):

The difference is the classloader being used. Tomcat has very specific rules for it's classloaders, some of them are counter intuitive. Your problem here, is that a class loaded in one classloader is not compatible with a class loaded in another. Even Object to Object will fail.

The jar containing your interface is loaded by the webapp classloader since it is located in the war-file. The implementation is loaded by the common classloader. This does not contain your interface, so it throws a ClassNotFoundException.

The solution is to move all jars into the same classloader. Either everything in the lib-folder, or everything in your war.

Implementing a plug-in architecture with Tomcat is a rather difficult undertaking. Using something like OSGi would probably help. But for small problems, it's probably overkill. Fun, but overkill.