# Is moving jar files from WEB-INF/lib and WEB-INF/lib-provided to <TOMCAT>/lib a good idea?

Tags: spring-mvc, jar, spring-boot, war, tomcat8

I have a `Spring Boot MVC Application` which I intend to deploy as `WAR` file in `Tomcat8`. I noticed, the WAR contains all dependencies on `WEB-INF/lib` and `WEB-INF/lib-provided` folders. I verified that moving all contents of these dependencies folders to `<TOMCATDIR>/lib` removes the necessity of having those jars in the `WEB-INF/lib*` folders, so I moved them all. The application is working as expected.

Suppose, I have many `WARs` that need to be deployed on the same server and most of them have similar dependencies. Having all the `JARs` in individual applications' library folders seems like a waste of space to me.

My question is, is it a good idea to move all the `JARs` from individual applications' library to the Tomcat's library? Will it cause me any problems in future? If it will, what sorts of problem am I likely to come across?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31138560/tomcat-8-classloading-difference-between-jar-in-web-inf-lib-and-tomcat-lib?rq=1

Comment: thank you. it is related, but does not fully answer my question.

Comment: As soon as two application have the same dependency in different versions, you will run into problems. Also, everytime you deploy your application, you have to remember to also update the JARs in the tomcat/lib folder, which will increase deployment complexity. I'm a big fan of self-contained deployment units, so i wouldn't use that folder at all. Disk space is not expensive any more.