# What will happen if [WEB-INF/lib] and [tomcat/lib] contain similar JARs?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jar, war, tomcat8

Today I was asked in an interview, *what will happen at the time of deployment if the Tomcat's `lib` and your `WEB-INF/lib` of the `war` file contains same `jar` file?*

I tested today in my machine, I didn't found any difference. Application is deploying successfully.

I have gone through with this [similar article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31138560/tomcat-8-classloading-difference-between-jar-in-web-inf-lib-and-tomcat-lib) , For, more clarification if anyone is having idea about what will happen if the Tomcat's `lib` and `WEB-INF/lib` contains same `jar` what will happen ??

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4739302/web-inf-classes-vs-web-inf-lib

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8364619/web-inf-classes-vs-web-inf-lib-jar-in-classpath-priority

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the jar contained in your `WEB-INF/lib` will be picked up by tomcat. The only caveat is core container jar's will be loaded in preference to jar's in `WEB-INF/lib`.

read : https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/class-loader-howto.html#Class_Loader_Definitions

Answer (score 1):

## Depends on `delegate` attribute

I haven't tried any of this. But it seems to hinge on value of the boolean `delegate` attribute.

And the way I read https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-10.0-doc/class-loader-howto.html#Class_Loader_Definitions is this:

For any webapp there are FOUR class loaders: bootstrap, system, common, webapp.

- By default the boolean `delegate` attribute is not specified and will default to `false`

  - => order of class loaders: `bootstrap`, **`webapp`**, `system`, `common`
  - => Your webapp's JAR wins.
- If, and only if, you explicitly specify `<Loader delegate="true"/>`

  - => order of class loaders: `bootstrap`, `system`, `common`, **`webapp`**
  - => `common` takes JARs from $CATALINA_BASE and $CATALINA_HOME
  - => Tomcat's JAR wins.

#### Further reading

Added info: This here is the documentation for the "delegate" attribute itself.

I find this slightly confusing, but it seems that Tomcat's default is to NOT follow Java's default. (Not sure wherever Java's default *"delegation model"* may have been defined.)

Quote from https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-10.0-doc/config/loader.html#Common_Attributes
(Formatting changed for emphasis.)

> - Set to **true** if you want the class loader to follow the standard Java2 delegation model, and attempt to load classes from parent class
>   loaders before looking inside the web application.
> - Set to **false** (the default) to have the class loader look inside the web application first, before asking parent class loaders to find
>   requested classes or resources.

Comment: Remark: there is an optional _shared_ classloader between _system_ and _common_.

Comment: @PiotrP.Karwasz. Great. Then it's even more complicated. :) Although for this specific question it wouldn't change the outcome.